# list item in new line using for loop in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

when I run following code in python 3.6, I got output in a window where text "first line, second line etc......" written in curly braces. My question is how can I get this text without curly braces. Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

lst = ['First line', 'Second line', 'Third line', 'Fourth line', 'Fifth line']

TT = Tk()
TT.title("")

def new_line() :
        result2 = []
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            result2.append(lst[i]+'\n')
        label2.configure(text=result2) 

label1 = Label(TT, text = 'values in new line :', bg='blue', fg='yellow', font = "Times 16 bold") #, height='10')
label1.grid(row=12, column=0, padx=8, pady=8)

label2 = Label(TT, justify=LEFT, bg='blue', fg='yellow', font = "Times 16 bold")
label2.grid(row=12, column=1, padx=8, pady=8)

new_line()

TT.maxsize()

TT.mainloop()
```

Comment: No you didn't. These are curly braces: `{}`. You got brackets: `[]`. The brackets mean that you have a list, but you need a string. Change `result2=[]` to `result2=""` and `result2.append(...)` to `result2+=...`.

Comment: Thanks, This method work for me !!!!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution provided to you through the comment, you can convert result2 to a string called, for example, `text`, and use the latter one as your label's text instead:

```
def new_line() :
   result2 = []
   for i in range(len(lst)):
       result2.append(lst[i]+'\n')
       text = ''.join(result2) # added this line
       label2.configure(text=text) # modified here
```

Demo:

[image]